# Select phenotypes to use for empires

Tags: stellaris

Is there a way to limit what phenotypes an empire will use for the pops/leaders?
Phenotype is what the game calls the different coloured pops.

Example: I want to set up a game with USA/China/Russia based space empires all using human as race (or 3 separate race definitions using the human model) but still have them look slightly different this way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Separate Human Phenotypes](https://steamcommunity.com/sharedfiles/filedetails/?id=685069894) mod allows this.

This mod splits humans into difference portraits, allowing you to make a species entirely of one race.

Unmodded, there is no way to do this.

Comment: This answer seems correct, but beware, answers like these are close to falling under the category of spam! Please read our [guide](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/promotion) so you don't accidentally post an answer that will be flagged as spam and deleted.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I added a description of the mod. Not sure what else I can do here.

Comment: The last line basically saying "no" technically answers the question. The info about the mod also solves my problem. As the asker I also don't see how it could be answered much better. Maybe pointing towards mods as a general solution since there could potentially be others also solving this in different ways? Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim I do agree that that's about as good as it'll get. Thanks for improving your answer! Every contribution helps.